# How read file vars to make global bars for roles?

Tags: ansible

How I load hosts.yml file from started playbook and the values are used in the roles.

I launch:

```
$ ansible-playbook proxy_squid.yml -i ./group_vars/hosts.yml -vvvvv
```

But I receive:

```
ansible-playbook 2.5.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.17 (default, Jul 20 2020, 15:37:01) [GCC 7.5.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
Parsed /home/user/repo/Iso27001/ansible/group_vars/hosts.yml inventory source with yaml plugin
Read vars_file './group_vars/vault_data.yml'
Read vars_file './group_vars/vault_ip.yml'
Read vars_file './group_vars/hosts.yml'
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.pyc

PLAYBOOK: proxy_squid.yml *****************************************************************
1 plays in proxy_squid.yml
Read vars_file './group_vars/vault_data.yml'
Read vars_file './group_vars/vault_ip.yml'
Read vars_file './group_vars/hosts.yml'
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'h_tmpvm' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/home/user/repo/ansible/proxy_squid.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Declaring conf
  ^ here
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is a weird idea `-i ./group_vars/hosts.yml` (to put an inventory into the group_vars directory). See [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#best-practices).

Comment: Hi @VladimirBotka, I make this... the values is not read by yml files in roles...

Comment: I think, you want to get informatons from the hosts.yml and want to use it in your playbook. In this case - you don't need to explicitly load the hosts.yml (don't put it into group_vars). All informations from hosts.yml is stored in a build-in variable called 'hostvars' and you can access it like https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found... python was not installed in the target host. Sorry...